# Redirecting URLs to end with .htm extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do you redirect urls to end with.htm using htaccess ? Meaning what htaccess code could be used to redirect all urls to end with .htm?
I tried [Redirect 302 * *.htm] but didn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: welcome to SO, please go through this - [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please give more information

Answer (score 0):

sometime ago I was told that it is possible to configure your server to parse html files as php (See as reference: https://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/). But I observed also that you can hide the ".php" information. (See reference: http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php).